# Parsing JSON with PHP multiple arrays to MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

stackoverflow newbie here. I've been reading through similar articles trying to piece together the code that I'm after. Fairly new to PHP and JSON, so here goes.

I'm trying to split some JSON data with the end goal of storing the data as two separate columns in a MySQL table. The JSON data looks like the below -

```
{
"request": {
    "command": "series",
    "series_id": "PET.RBRTE.A"
},
"series": [{
    "series_id": "PET.RBRTE.A",
    "name": "Europe Brent Spot Price FOB, Annual",
    "units": "Dollars per Barrel",
    "f": "A",
    "unitsshort": "$\/bbl",
    "description": "Europe Brent Spot Price FOB",
    "copyright": "Thomson-Reuters",
    "source": "Thomson-Reuters",
    "start": "1987",
    "end": "2015",
    "updated": "2016-05-16T16:56:05-0400",
    "data": [
        ["2015", 52.32],
        ["2014", 98.97],
        ["2013", 108.56],
        ...
    ]
}]
```

This JSON data is available direct via a URL so I'm using `$json = file_get_contents` and `$array = json_decode($json, true)` to get the data initially into an array.

Dumping the array `var_dump($array)` shows it as the following -

```
Array
(

[request] => Array
    (
        [command] => series
        [series_id] => PET.RBRTE.A
    )

[series] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [series_id] => PET.RBRTE.A
                [name] => Europe Brent Spot Price FOB, Annual
                [units] => Dollars per Barrel
                [f] => A
                [unitsshort] => $/bbl
                [description] => Europe Brent Spot Price FOB
                [copyright] => Thomson-Reuters
                [source] => Thomson-Reuters
                [start] => 1987
                [end] => 2015
                [updated] => 2016-05-16T16:56:05-0400
                [data] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2015
                                [1] => 52.32
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2014
                                [1] => 98.97
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 2013
                                [1] => 108.56
                            )
                        [3] ...
                    )

            )

    )
```

All good so far. I then wanted to obtain the sub-array data with the `data` array series, of which there are 29 in this particular JSON dataset. [0] within each sub-array is a date (year) and [1] is a value associated with that year.

The closest I've been able to get to this data is with the code below -

```
$array_data = implode(",", $array['series'][0]['data'][0]);
```

Which when using `echo '<pre>'; print_r(($array_data)); echo '</pre>';` gives me `2015,52.32`, but what I'd like to get is the result for each of the sub-arrays as their own variable that I can then use to insert into MySQL, for example -

```
2015,52.32
2014,98.97
2013,108.56
...,...
```

I would then use an insert statement to add the first value into a datetype column and the second value into a decimal column.

I feel I'm going about this the long way round, so if anyone has suggestions on how to improve this to get the end result, I would be most grateful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you want to combine the two values together to insert into your database? Shouldn't each go into its own column?

Comment: Its not the long way around, just write the code

Comment: Yes that is correct, each value should go into its own column. So ideally I should be able to parse the 'date' into one column and the 'value' into another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
$dataArray = $array['series'][0]['data'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) {
  $implosion = $dataArray[$i]);
}
```

If you want a dictionary:

```
$dataArray = $array['series'][0]['data'];
$dict = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) {
  $dict[dataArray[$i][0]] = $dataArray[$i][1];
}
```

Giving:

```
Array
(
[2015] => 52.32
...
)
```

**EDIT** For separate loops:

```
$dataArray = $array['series'][0]['data'];
$dates = [];
$values = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($dataArray); $i++) {
  array_push($dates, $dataArray[$i][0]); 
  array_push($values, $dataArray[$i][1]);
}

$dateImplosion = implode(", ", $dates);
echo $dateImplosion;
```

Comment: I think a foreach would work very well here rather than a for loop!

Comment: Thank you Nick. Is it possible to have two separate 'implosions', one for the 'date' and the other for the 'value' that I can then use within an SQL insert statement? i.e.  $implosion = implode(",", $array['series'][0]['data'][$i] as $date);

Comment: Either will do! I just used a for loop because I'm old school like that

Comment: If you want two separate arrays, just do array_push($dates, $array['series'][0]['data'][$i][0]); array_push($values, $array['series'][0]['data'][$i][1]); in the loop, where $dates and $values are new arrays instantiated above the for loop.

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` and add to question, let me think. EDIT, nope should work I think... Interesting! I'll test.

Comment: Sorry Nick, just realised I put the echo within the loop, which explains the output! I guess I will need to serialise these arrays before importing to MySQL i.e. $mydates = var_export(serialize($dates), true); or run a loop to insert each row of the arrays in a table?